# Drupal 7: Private filesystem path set to /

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have a problem.
I set the private path to / and now all my URLs return error 500.

Yes I'm an idiot. How do I reverse this without doing a clean install?

/Anders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit that variable directly in the `variable` table of the database, the variable name is `file_private_path`. e.g.

```
UPDATE variable SET value = '/new/path' WHERE name = 'file_private_path'
```

It would probably be a good idea to manually clear Drupal's cache afterwards which simply means truncating all tables whose name begins with `cache`, e.g, in MySQL:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE cache
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_block
```

etc...

Comment: Tried, unfortunatly, I'm still getting Error 500 :(

Comment: Actually it was PART of the solution - the rest was removing the .htaccess file that is generated. Thanks!